# How do I resolve an intermittent TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.el.parentNode.replaceChild') in mozart?

Tags: mozart-mvc

In my mozart App, every couple of page loads, I get this JS error:

"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.el.parentNode.replaceChild')
           at https://cdn.bigcommerce.com/mozart/0.1.9/mozart.min.js:1
           at https://cdn.bigcommerce.com/mozart/0.1.9/mozart.min.js:1
           at https://cdn.bigcommerce.com/mozart/0.1.9/mozart.min.js:2
           at https://cdn.bigcommerce.com/mozart/0.1.9/mozart.min.js:2
           at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js:1"

My app body on the index page looks like:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    App.start({ rootElement: '#RunwayContainer'});
  </script>
  <div id="RunwayContainer"></div>
</body>
```

All I'm doing in my view is a simple

{{#collection "App.PlayListItemView" collectionObserveBinding="plays"}}
placeholder
{{/collection}}

It seems like I can reproduce this reliably by forcing a cache refresh.

How can we fix this? It's causing my tests to fail, and means we can't get this in front of customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your App.start function creates a Layout and then calls bindRoot(rootElement) on it, you need to either:

(a) Move the App.Start call to *after* the div

or

(b) Wrap the whole App.Start call in a $(document).ready

The render engine will blow up if the Layout can't find the root element - this occurs intermittently in your code because of the race condition of whether the script runs before the div becomes available in the DOM (A shift-refresh will cause it to fail consistently).

This is a very obscure error and a warning will be added in the next version of Mozart if Layout cannot find the root element.

Comment: Thanks, I moved the App.Start call and now it works perfectly.